# Google Apps Script: Save Spreadsheet as ODS for Local Backup

Tags: excel, csv, google-apps-script, backup, ods

I could use a hand. My company uses Google Sheets extensively, and we need a way to access files when we lose our Internet connection.

I could not get any of the examples found on this site to work for creating xls or ods from Google Sheets via script.

I did script a way to create csv backups, accessible from a local Google Drive folder. When used with an hourly trigger, this script creates csv files of every sheet of any spreadsheet modified in the last hour, puts them in a folder, and zips it inside a folder specifically for backups. From there I can move the zip to our local server.

```
function backUpMaker() {
  var backupFolderId = '<Id of Backup Folder>';
  var timeNow = new Date();  
  var newFolder = DocsList.createFolder(timeNow);
  var newFolderId =newFolder.getId();
  newFolder.addToFolder(DocsList.getFolderById(backupFolderId));
  newFolder.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var sheets = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (sheets.hasNext()) {
    var sheet = sheets.next();
    var lastUpdate = sheet.getLastUpdated();
    var timeHourAgo = new Date();
    timeHourAgo = timeNow - 3600000;
    if(lastUpdate >= timeHourAgo){
      var sheetId = sheet.getId();
      var csv = eachSheet(sheetId,newFolderId); 
    }
  }
  var backupFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(backupFolderId);
  try{
    backupFolder.createFile(Utilities.zip(newFolder.getFiles(), timeNow + '.zip'));
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
  newFolder.setTrashed(true);
}

function eachSheet(key,newFolderId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var ssName = ss.getName();
  var howManySheets = ss.getNumSheets();
  try{
   for (var sheetIndex=0; sheetIndex < howManySheets; sheetIndex++) {   
     var activeSheet = ss.getSheets()[sheetIndex];
     var activeName = activeSheet.getName();
     if(activeName != 'Dropdowns'){     //Skip a hidden sheet used for validation on many of our spreadsheets
      var activeId = activeSheet.getSheetId();
      var time = new Date();
      var fileName = time + " Backup: " + ssName + " " + activeName + ".csv";
      var csv = contentCSV(ssId,activeId);
      var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(newFolderId);  
      folder.createFile(fileName, csv, 'text/plain');
     }
   } 
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err)
  }
}

function contentCSV(key,gid) {
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(key);  
  var response =     UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + key + 
                "&gid=" + gid + "&exportFormat=csv", oAuth());
  var fileText = response.getContentText();  
  return fileText;
}

function oAuth() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
  var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" 
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");   
 var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
  };
  return requestData;
}
```

How would I modify this to save as ods rather than csv? Or is there a better way to save backups? Thank you for your help!

**Working code follows, thanks to input by @serge-insas :**

Note: To make this work, enter your backup folder's id key, then choose ods or xlsx by commenting out the other choice. Then you need to set up a timed hourly trigger for backUpMaker(). Logs will catch errors for files that have been moved temporarily. Here goes:

```
function backUpMaker() {
  var backupFolderId = '0B5--------------------1ZX1k';
  //var exportFormat = 'ods';
  var exportFormat = 'xlsx';
  var timeNow = new Date();  
  var newFolder = DocsList.createFolder(timeNow);
  var newFolderId =newFolder.getId();
  newFolder.addToFolder(DocsList.getFolderById(backupFolderId));
  newFolder.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var sheets = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (sheets.hasNext()) {
    var sheet = sheets.next();
    var lastUpdate = sheet.getLastUpdated();
    var timeHourAgo = new Date();
    timeHourAgo = timeNow - 3600000;
    if(lastUpdate >= timeHourAgo){
      try{
      var key = sheet.getId();
      var name = sheet.getName();
      var fileName = timeNow + " Backup: " + name + "." + exportFormat;
      var blob = contentBackup(key,exportFormat);
      var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(newFolderId);  
      folder.createFile(blob).rename(fileName);
      } catch(err){
        Logger.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
  var backupFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(backupFolderId);
  try{
    backupFolder.createFile(Utilities.zip(newFolder.getFiles(), timeNow + '.zip'));
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
  newFolder.setTrashed(true);
}

function contentBackup(key,exportFormat) {
  try{
    if(exportFormat == 'xlsx'){
      exportFormat = 'xls';
    }  
    var file = DocsList.getFileById(key);  
    var response =     UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + key + 
                  "&exportFormat=" + exportFormat, oAuth());
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob();  
    return fileBlob;
    } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err)
    }
}

function oAuth() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
  var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" 
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");   
 var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
  };
  return requestData;
}
```

Comment: Why not just enable Drive offline access?

Comment: @ZigMandel, yeah, I thought of that, but I don't have access to everyone's browser. Oddly this is easier.

Comment: but with offline access you can even modify the spreadsheet and changes will be saved later

Comment: Good point. The next time the IT guy comes around I'll have him install Google Drive on everyone's computer and enable offline access. Until then, this code will keep us alive. Out of curiosity, what happens later when multiple people access the same file offline and make changes? One of our spreadsheets regularly has 8 people on it at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needed very few changes to get ods files.

2 differences : the requested format in the urlFetch becomes "ods" and the returned object is not a string anymore but a blob.

Beside that, I kept all the sheet selection functions that you wrote and it seems to work fine as well. (nice job you did !).

Below is the full code I reproduced from yours and changed as described. My tests were working fine.

```
function backUpMaker() {
  var backupFolderId = '0B3qS--------------TXdlY2M';
  var timeNow = new Date();  
  var newFolder = DocsList.createFolder(timeNow);
  var newFolderId =newFolder.getId();
  newFolder.addToFolder(DocsList.getFolderById(backupFolderId));
  newFolder.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var sheets = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (sheets.hasNext()) {
    var sheet = sheets.next();
    var lastUpdate = sheet.getLastUpdated();
    var timeHourAgo = new Date();
    timeHourAgo = timeNow - 3600000;
    if(lastUpdate >= timeHourAgo){
      var sheetId = sheet.getId();
      var csv = eachSheet(sheetId,newFolderId); 
    }
  }
  var backupFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(backupFolderId);
  try{
    backupFolder.createFile(Utilities.zip(newFolder.getFiles(), timeNow + '.zip'));
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
  newFolder.setTrashed(true);
}

function eachSheet(key,newFolderId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var ssName = ss.getName();
  var howManySheets = ss.getNumSheets();
  try{
   for (var sheetIndex=0; sheetIndex < howManySheets; sheetIndex++) {   
     var activeSheet = ss.getSheets()[sheetIndex];
     var activeName = activeSheet.getName();
     if(activeName != 'Dropdowns'){     //Skip a hidden sheet used for validation on many of our spreadsheets
      var activeId = activeSheet.getSheetId();
      var time = new Date();
      var fileName = time + " Backup: " + ssName + " " + activeName + ".ods";
      var blob = contentODS(ssId,activeId);
      var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(newFolderId);  
      folder.createFile(blob).rename(fileName);
     }
   } 
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err)
  }
}

function contentODS(key,gid) {
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(key);  
  var response =     UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + key + 
                "&gid=" + gid + "&exportFormat=ods", oAuth());
  var fileBlob = response.getBlob();  
  return fileBlob;
}

function oAuth() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
  var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" 
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");   
 var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
  };
  return requestData;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Unlike the csv version, it appears that with ods I no longer need to create a separate file for each sheet in the spreadsheet, it will save the whole spreadsheet in one ods file. Is that correct?

Comment: It is indeed. Ods is "full featured " format... you can also get xlsx format with the same code, simply change in the urlFetch call. Btw, please consider accepting the answer.    Thanks

Comment: Answer accepted. I can't tell you how happy I am that this works. I'll post the code without the sheet selector momentarily, otherwise you'll get duplicate ods files. Then if someone else needs something like this, you can just copy and paste. When I tried to create blobs before I think I was making it too complicated and couldn't get it to produce anything but a PDF.

Comment: Working code posted below original question, will work for ods or xlsx depending on which line you comment out.