# Converting google spreadsheet to XLSX or ODS using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to convert a few google spreadsheets to Excel (xlsx preferred).
I've read several threads about how to achieve this, but I can't get it running.
Amongst the threads I've read are [Google Apps Script: Save Spreadsheet as ODS for Local Backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493203/google-apps-script-save-spreadsheet-as-ods-for-local-backup) and [Google apps script to email google spreadsheet excel version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712137/google-apps-script-to-email-google-spreadsheet-excel-version)

In order to stay close to code I've found AND get more info about why it doesn't work, I modified code I found such that it just handles a few files and also try-catch has been removed.

```
****************** Not working code **************
function contentODS(key, gid) 
{
   var file = DocsList.getFileById(key); 

   var fetchParameters = oAuth();

   var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + key + "&gid=" + gid + "&exportFormat=ods";
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchParameters);

   var fileBlob = response.getBlob();  
   return fileBlob;
}

function oAuth()
{ // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493203/google-apps-script-save-spreadsheet-as-ods-for-local-backup
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
  var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" 
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=" + scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");   

  var requestData =
  {
    "oAuthServiceName":   "spreadsheets",
    "oAuthUseToken":      "always",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "method":             "DELETE",
  };
  return requestData;
}

function eachSheet(key, newFolderId)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var ssName = ss.getName();
  var howManySheets = ss.getNumSheets();

  for (var sheetIndex=0; sheetIndex < howManySheets; sheetIndex++)
  {   
     var activeSheet = ss.getSheets()[sheetIndex];
     var activeName = activeSheet.getName();
     var activeId = activeSheet.getSheetId();
     var time = new Date();
     var fileName = time + " Backup: " + ssName + " " + activeName + ".ods";
     var blob = contentODS(ssId, activeId);
     var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(newFolderId);  
     folder.createFile(blob).rename(fileName);
   } 
}

function backUpMaker()
{
  var backupDirectory = 'Backup';
  var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFoldersByName(backupDirectory);
  var backupFolderId = undefined;
  if (folders.hasNext()) backupFolderId = folders.next().getId();
  else return;  // File doe not exist

  var timeNow = new Date();  
  var newFolder = DocsList.createFolder(timeNow);
  var newFolderId = newFolder.getId();
  newFolder.addToFolder(DocsList.getFolderById(backupFolderId));
  newFolder.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
  var sheets = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (sheets.hasNext())
  {
    var sheet = sheets.next();
    var name = sheet.getName();

    var filesToSave = [ 'My-Agenda', 'My-Kalender' ];
    var numFiles = filesToSave.length;

    for (var i=0; i<numFiles; i++)
    {
       if (name == filesToSave[i])
       {
          var sheetId = sheet.getId();
          var csv = eachSheet(sheetId, newFolderId); 
          break;
       }  
    }   
  }
  var backupFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(backupFolderId);
  var newFiles = newFolder.getFiles();
  var numFiles = newFiles.length;

  if (numFiles > 0)
  {
     var nameZipFile = timeNow + '.zip';
     backupFolder.createFile(Utilities.zip(newFiles, nameZipFile));
  } 

  newFolder.setTrashed(true);
}
```

Running backupmaker fails at `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchParameters);`
and indicates    verification for service spreadsheets failed

Waht should I do to make it work.

Comment: Are you using new version of spreadsheet?

Comment: @SergeInsas I must say "I don't know" . I created spreadsheets using SpreadsheetApp and also using the red "create" button on Google Drive.  Can you be more specific so I CAN provide a real answer

Comment: The new version has a small green icon at the bottom with a "v" in it (like a sort of check box) and defaults to 1000 rows instead of 100 among other differences...it is also the version that has an add on menu.

Comment: Yes, indeed I'm using the new version.

Comment: That's why the code you are referencing to does not work actually... The url used to call the urlFetch are only useable with old version. I searched for a solution but although I found the code for pdf conversion all the tests I made to get xls conversion have failed... so, for now, I can't provide a solution for you, sorry.

Comment: Another codebreaker by Google.....  The PDF conversion can be useful as well. Did you post it already? Thanks for the reference

Comment: I found it on Amit Agarwal's site : [http://ctrlq.org/code/19699-email-google-spreadsheet-as-pdf](http://ctrlq.org/code/19699-email-google-spreadsheet-as-pdf)  I tested it successfully ;)

Comment: btw, you have 2 pending questions I answered, are these answers not acceptable in your opinion ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed those answers. I upvoted the comments now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to get the export URL and use the script's OAuth2 token to download the file.

```
function exportAsExcel(spreadsheetId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(spreadsheetId);
  var url = file.exportLinks['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });
  return response.getBlob();
}

function test() {
  var spreadsheetId = 'SPREADSHEET ID HERE';
  DriveApp.createFile(exportAsExcel(spreadsheetId));
}
```

Comment: As a follow up question : is it possible to create an Excel spreadsheet and writing to it like to a Google spreadsheet?  I tried  `DriveApp.createFile('newExcelFile', '','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' );` This does create the file, it doesn't have a sheet in it nor can I use it with SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no API to do cell-by-cell manipulations of an Excel file stored in Drive. You would have to download the file, edit it locally using a library, and re-upload it. Alternatively, you could upload one and convert it to a Google Spreadsheet using `convert: true` in the request.